# Using JSON over HTTP as peer to peer?

Tags: json, http, p2p

I am revising for an exam and am a bit confused. If for example, an object is being transferred over HTTP (httpwebrequest?), would this be a peer to peer application?

sorry if this is vague, I dont know much about this :(

Answer (score 1):

Not likely, it's probably "client-server", client being a "thin-client" like Internet Explorer or Firefox, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can't tell from just the fact that it's JSON over HTTP. For example, a peer-to-peer file sharing program could use JSON over HTTP peer-to-peer if it wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, it is still client/server, because you are requesting a resource and the server gives it to you. Ther is no way to the server to request anything from the client.